# custom header for multimerch in opencart

Tags: opencart

I need a secondary header for all the multimerch files.

In .tpl files , I can find php echo $ header;

But in the controller file, I cant find declaration for header.

I have also tried finding in vqmod but no progress.

So I declared the custom header variable.

But now the pages are blank

Please help

Opencart v 2.0.2.0

Answer (score -2):

I believe it is left the same as in 1.5.x -> at the bottom of the controller you will see " $this->children = array( ...". Here are included other elements, header should be included here as well)